# Como adicionar variável na query como coluna?

Tags: php, query, mysqli

Como faço pra adicionar a variável `$pesq` como coluna de uma consulta ( nao de pesquisa) da query?

```
$pesq = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon , $_POST['pesq']);
$pesquisa = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon , $_POST['pesquisa']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbcliente WHERE '$pesq' = '$pesquisa'";
```

Comment: Ponto de pesquisa? em nomes de colunas não se coloca aspas simples.

Comment: é... era só tirar as aspas msm... q burro... brigado rray

Comment: Editei para que as pessoas entendam melhor, acho que era isto o que queria, se não for basta clicar em "Reverter": https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/218510/revisions

Comment: Sim é possível! só remova aquelas aspas simples, desde que o campo exista na tabela vai funcionar.